# Detect and Draw Contours with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have this error in my console:

```
File "c:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/contornoscongranny.py", line 13, in <module>
    cv2.drawContours(img, ctns, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'
```

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

camino= "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg"
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg")

grises= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

bordes= cv2.Canny(grises, 100, 200)

_, ctns, = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img, ctns, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
print ('Numero de contornos es ', len(ctns))
texto= 'Contornos encontrados ' + str(len(ctns))

cv2.putText(img, texto, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7,  
    (255, 0, 0), 1)


cv2.imshow('Bordes', bordes)
cv2.imshow('Imagen', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

how can i resolve it?

Comment: I assume, you have OpenCV 4.x, since this line: `_, ctns, = cv2.findContours(...)` seems to compile (otherwise you'd get another error message), and I can reproduce your exact error. Change that to `ctns, _ = cv2.findContours(...)`. If you use OpenCV 3.x, as I said, you should get another error message, but for completeness, it should be `_, ctns, _ = cv2.findContours(...)` then. Please try the fitting option, and see, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drawing the contours, we can use:

```
ctns = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ctns = ctns[0] if len(ctns)==2 else ctns[1]
for c in ctns:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[c], -1,(0,0,255),2)
```

This will draw the contours on the image. If you can share a sample image on which you are trying to make the contours, I would be able to help more

Comment: hello, i upload the image here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920162/obtain-only-external-contours-with-open

Comment: Since it works, you can upvote my answer @AgustinCoronel