# Obtain only external contours in image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have this code, that draws contours in my image, but I need only the external contours:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

camino= "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg"
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg")

grises= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

bordes= cv2.Canny(grises, 100, 250)

ctns = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ctns = ctns[0] if len(ctns)==2 else ctns[1]
for c in ctns:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[c], -1,(0,0,255),2)

print ('Numero de contornos es ', len(ctns))
texto= 'Contornos encontrados ' + str(len(ctns))

cv2.putText(img, texto, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7,  
    (255, 0, 0), 1)


cv2.imshow('Bordes', bordes)
cv2.imshow('Imagen', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows().
```

This is my original image:
[image: original image]

This is the obtained image with the contours:
[image: the obtained image with the contours]

In this case I just only need to detect 10 contours 1 for each entity, but it detects 450 contours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using thresholding + morphological operations + contour filtering

First we convert to grayscale then Otsu's threshold for a binary image (left) then remove dotted lines using contour area filtering (right)

[image]
[image]

From here we perform morph close to remove the text then invert the image (left). We find contours and fill all contours smaller than a threshold to black (right)

[image]
[image]

Next we invert again and perform morph open with a large rectangle kernel to remove the small edges and spikes

[image]

Finally we find contours to get our result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove dotted lines
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Fill contours
close_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, close_kernel, iterations=6)
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 15000:
        cv2.drawContours(close, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Smooth contours
close = 255 - close
open_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20,20))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, open_kernel, iterations=3)

# Find contours and draw result
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: hello, your code works for some images but now i need to do the same with another schemas like sqlserver phpmyadmin etc, could you help me please? here is the query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852382/crop-rectangle-from-a-image-with-opencv?noredirect=1#comment105862975_59852382

Comment: Try adjusting the kernel sizes and the number of iterations. It's difficult to get a solution that works for all images

Comment: Those are the questions and answers I really like

Answer (score 0):

You can try flood fill combined with some morph operators.

Comment: I think you should spread your answer